# How to create a class inside Microsoft Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

May be it's a wrong question, but I need to create a Model/class and access same in azure function. I could not able to find how can I create a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Functions - Shared classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540951/azure-functions-shared-classes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Classes may be created inline as it would typically define a class in a regular C# project. [Here's an example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/dev/sample/HttpTrigger-CSharp-Poco/run.csx) of a function that defines a class.

You can also define classes in separate files and reference those files using the `#load` directive as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#reusing-csx-code).

Another option is to reference an assembly where your classes are defined, as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies).

And, a different approach, and yet another option, is to use the newly announced [Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/)