# Deploy Azure Function with dependency on Web Application's classes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am reviewing Azure Functions to implement a micro service that is associated with our main ASP.net Core application (version 3.1 until .net 6 is released).  The Azure function will require classes that are defined in our main application (I am reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540951/azure-functions-shared-classes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007141/how-to-create-a-class-inside-microsoft-azure-function) thread for that purpose, even though these threads are quite old).

Because of the dependency on these classes, I would like to include the Azure Functions in our main repository and include a pipeline in Azure DevOps for the Azure Function, next to the pipeline for our web application.  In my thought this means that we don't have to check if there is a change in the dependent classes to deploy a new release for the Azure Function, as *any* commit will trigger a new release.

Is this the common or intended workflow for deploying Azure Functions with a dependency on other applications' classes?

Comment: Following Martin Brandl's answer, this seems to be a good resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a .NET Standard Class Library where you share your Code / Models between your ASP.NET Core Application and your Azure Function (e. g. **MyApplication.Core** or **MyApplication.Models**)
Then you usually want to configure your pipeline to only run when a change happens in a certain path - like:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: master
  paths:
    include: 
      - src/MyFunction
      - src/MyApplication.Models
```